# What is the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to - \infty} \frac{x+y}{x-y}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to evaluate the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to - \infty} \frac{x+y}{x-y}.
$$

Is there a way of making sense of it?

For example, if we perform the limit on $x$ at $y=0$ we get
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to - \infty} \frac{x}{x} = 1,
$$
and for $x=0$
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to - \infty} \frac{-y}{y} = -1,
$$
which implies that the limit should not be defined.

However, intuitively the denominator ($\infty + \infty$) should be much higher than the numerator ($\infty-\infty$) which makes me think that this limit may be zero. The reason I am asking is because I am finding this limit in a physical observable.

Comment: @Ajay That's NOT the case.

Comment: Is this expression a limit of a limit
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left(\lim_{y \to - \infty}{\frac{x+y}{x-y}}\right)}$$
or a multivariable limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty, -\infty)}{\frac{x+y}{x-y}}$$
?

The first evaluates to -1, while the second is undefined.

Comment: I am not sure. I think it is a limit of a limit. However the order in which I take the limit ($x$ or $y$ first) should not matter. If I take the $y$ limit first I get -1, as you noted, and if I take the $x$ limit first I get 1. This is the reason I am a bit lost.

Comment: Could you provide the context in which you found this expression? If its value should be order-agnostic, it seems to me it may be the undefined multivariable limit.

Comment: What makes you say that the order of the limits should not matter? That's false.

Comment: You just showed that the order in which you take the limit matters.

Comment: As a said it is a physical problem. I am using the LSZ reduction formula to compute a scattering process in quantum field theory. In this context $y$ is the initial time of the particle and $x$ the final time (in the process).

Comment: @jjagmath Sorry, I mean that the order in the specific problem that I'm studying should not matter, at least intuitively. What I mean is that I should get the same limit independently of the order.

Comment: @Aruera So does this limit arise in something of the form of a doubly-improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(x) \, \mathrm{d}t}$? If so I believe that this should be the multivariable limit, and hence undefined.

Comment: Yes, the limit comes exactly from an improper integral. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lemmon the limit comes from evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx dy \partial_x \partial_y f(x,y)$ where the function $f$ is zero when $y \to \infty$ or $x \to - \infty$. Is this still a multivariable limit?

Comment: I'm sorry that this probably doesn't help, but it depends on the meaning of the notation. I am no good at understanding the physics notation for integrals, but a doubly-improper integral does require the multivariable limit. If the above can be parametrized to depend on time $t$ by some function $g$ as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty,-\infty)}{\int_y^x{g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}}$ then yes, this does require the multivariable limit.

Comment: @Lemmon Thank you very much! you helped me a lot.

Comment: Does your $g(t)$ go to 0 in both tails? It sounds like both tails are thick and undefined in isolation. Given how you’ve described the problem - it sounds like you might need to make some assumptions about the relative size of x and y to get a real answer. If you have more context in the original problem of what you’re trying to do, people could probably give better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to evaluate the expression, as usual, from the inside out. That means that you need to consider $x$ fixed, and evaluate $$\lim_{y\to - \infty}\frac{x+y}{x-y} = -1$$

So it actually doesn't depends on $x$.

Now
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{y\to - \infty}\frac{x+y}{x-y} = \lim_{x\to\infty}(-1)=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the opposite approach to JJagmath, and treating this as a multivariable limit, the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty, -\infty)}{\frac{x+y}{x-y}}$ does not exist. This can be seen by taking two different paths to $(\infty, -\infty)$. Letting $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{x-y}$, and assuming the limit $L$ is defined, we have
$$L = \lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty, -\infty)}{f(x,y)} = \lim_{t \to \infty}{f(t,-t)} = \lim_{t\to\infty}{\frac{t-t}{t+t}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}{0} = 0\,\text{, but}\\
L = \lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty, -\infty)}{f(x,y)} = \lim_{t \to \infty}{f(2t,-t)} = \lim_{t\to\infty}{\frac{2t-t}{2t+t}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}{\frac{t}{3t}} = \lim_{t\to\infty}{\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{3}\,\text{.}$$

Thus, if the limit is defined, we have $0 = L = \frac{1}{3}$, but this is a contradiction, as $0 \neq \frac{1}{3}$. Thus the limit is undefined.