# How to perform the following limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to perform the following limit:
$$
I=\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to -\infty} \frac{1}{x-y} \int_y^x f(z) dz,
$$
where the function f(z) is
$$
f(z) = 
\begin{cases}
        f(a) & \text{if } z < a \\
        g(z) & \text{if } b < z < a \\
        f(b) & \text{if } z > b
\end{cases}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $g(z)$ in a analytical function with $g(a)=f(a)$ and $g(b) = f(b)$.

Intuitively, the result of the limit should be
$$
I = \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.
$$

However, if I expand the integral
$$
\frac{1}{x-y} \int_y^x f(z) dz = \frac{a-y}{x-y} f(a) + \frac{1}{x-y} \int_a^b g(z) dz + \frac{x-b}{x-y} f(b) \\
 = \frac{a-y}{x-y} f(a) + \frac{b-a}{x-y} g(c)+ \frac{x-b}{x-y} f(b),
$$
where in the last step I have used the mean value theorem and $b<c<a$. Neglecting the terms that vanish once I take the limit, I can write
$$
I = \lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to -\infty} \frac{f(b) x -f(a) y}{x-y}
= \lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to -\infty} 
\left[
\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} + \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2} \frac{x+y}{x-y}
\right]
$$
which looks like an [undefined limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687917/what-is-the-limit-lim-x-to-infty-lim-y-to-infty-fracxyx-y/4687921#4687921).

Am I doing something wrong? Is this limit undefined?

Comment: Isn't it clear that $I=f(a)$?

Comment: You should already know [what the limit of that quotient is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4687921/1104384).

Comment: @Bruno B, yes. I've decided to redo the question since it is a limit from an indefinite integral it may be cleares what the answer is.